# The JMS receiver thread and the onMessage() callback

Tags: jms

I have looked at similar threads but did not get a satisfactory reply.

In the JMS receiver thread, I see a while loop coded as follows:

`while(true)
{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}`

The above thread also has a registered listener attached to it, which implements the messageListener interface and thus provides for the the callback onMessage() event.

When the onMessage() event gets triggered on the listener, what happens to the receiver thread?

Does its state become false? Does it get interrupted (and throws an interrupted exception)?

What exactly happens at the while loop stated above?

Answer (score 0):

The code above is simply saying 'wait forever' - it most likely is a hastily designed way of NOT ending this thread before someone hits Ctrl-C. The code of while(true) will always be true, so it just blocks here until this thread is interrupted. There is no magic inside this thread !

However in your second (invisible) 'message dispatcher thread' that has been automatically created in Connection.start() messages are received and dispatched to your onMessage() method. Until you call Connection.stop() or your exit your program.